# How to prove that a $\lambda$-system , being closed under countable disjoint unions, is also closed under finite disjoint unions?

Tags: measure-theory

A $\lambda$-system is a set $X$ along with $S$, a collection  of subsets of $X$ with the following properties :

(i) $\varnothing \in S$ 
(ii) If $A \in S$ then $A^{c} = X \setminus A \in S$   ($S$ is closed under complementation) 
(iii) If $A_{1}, A_{2}, ... \in S$ and are pairwise-disjoint, then $\bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}}^{} A_{i} \in S $ ($S$ is closed under countable disjoint unions)

How can one prove that S is also closed under *finite* disjoint unions ?  (1)

The closest I've been able to come is to prove that if $A_{1}, A_{2}, ... \in S$ and are pairwise-disjoint then the union of any finite number of the $A_{i}$ is also in $S$, that is to say, $\bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{F}}^{} A_{i} \in S$ for all finite $F \subset \mathbb{N}$

Proof :

Let $\alpha = \bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}}^{} A_{i}$ and $F$ be a finite subset of $\mathbb{N}$

Then $\bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N} \setminus F}^{} A_{i} \in S$ by (iii) and
$\alpha^{c} \in S$ by (ii)

Let $P = \alpha^{c} \cup  \bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N} \setminus F}^{} A_{i}$ 
Then $P \in S$ by (iii) and $P^{c} = \bigcup_{i \in F} A_{i} \in S$ by (ii)

Since $F$ can be chosen to be any finite subset of $\mathbb{N}$ then $\bigcup_{i \in F} A_{i} \in S$ for all finite $F \subset \mathbb{N}$

However I'm not sure how to prove the general case referred to in (1).

Comment: Take the remaining sets to be the empty set, $\emptyset$ in (iii).

Comment: Thank you! It hadn’t occurred to me that the empty set is disjoint with itself.

Comment: @peek-a-boo , would you mind posting your comment above as an answer? I can then accept it as correct.

Comment: you can answer your own question (it’s really simple and besides, I think it has been asked elsewhere…just too lazy to search for the dupe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per @peek-a-boo's comment, for pairwise-disjoint $A_{1}, A_{2}, ..., A_{n} \in S$, set $A_{k} = \varnothing$ for all $k > n$. The result follows from (iii).